# Gnosis Safe on Fantom

Tags: gnosis-safe, multisignature, fantom

There seems to be unofficial Gnosis Safe launched on Fantom blockchain.

https://docs.fantom.foundation/staking/fantom-safe

Does this solution have the same API that Gnosis Safe provides to get information about safes?

https://safe-transaction.mainnet.gnosis.io/

Answer (score 1):

> Does this solution have the same API that Gnosis Safe provides to get information about safes?

No, it doesn't appear that it does. You can always get the information by connecting to a node, however.

Comment: Do you mean I could get the same data from safe smart-contracts? I would like to get all balances of the safe

Comment: Yes, that should be possible with the `balanceOf` function of the ERC20 tokens. Here's the spec: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20

Comment: Doesn't Safe hold any aggregated information on this?